# What is the correct database to choose for a lot of records?

Tags: database, nosql, blockchain

As part of my project in the cryptocurrency field I have to get transaction for specific wallet,
web3.js (the library I'm using to connect to the blockchain) has limitation, I can't just type wallet hash and get the transactions so I have to go through all blockchain to look for that.

I try to build my own cryptocurrency transaction database. There are few billions transaction and for that I chose to use noSQL database.
the question is:
what is the correct database to work with? Debating between Cassandra or MongoDB.

I'm aiming to get the output as fast as possible.